# RMTileCache background caching never reaches totalTiles count and never tells delegate it finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, mapbox

I'm using MapBox and RMTileCache's beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource: to preload tiles before rendering maps in my client app. I want to preload the tiles for the currently visible area of the map from zoom level 3 thru zoom level 7. So, I pass the current bounds of my mapView using the rect returned from [mapView latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox]. My ViewController implements RMTileCacheBackgroundDelegate so as to get callbacks as the caching occurs and then completes. I do receive callbacks on didBeginBackgroundCacheWithCount:forTileSource: and didBackgroundCacheTile:withIndex:ofTotalTileCount: However, tileCacheDidFinishBackgroundCache: is never called.

I stepped thru the source of RMTileCache and noticed that the actual count of cached tiles in "progTile" never reaches the calculated total count in "totalTiles". Therefore, the final callback, tileCacheDidFinishBackgroundCache:, is not reached.

I'm not sure how to change (or if I should change) the totalTiles calculation. Perhaps I am passing the wrong viewing rect in my initial call? I'm not totally clear if that is correct. I can create a simple fix that calls tileCacheDidFinishBackgroundCache: in the case that caching simply finishes, but this seems to just hide the issue. Any guidance here would be appreciated.

For reference, my test code is straight forward:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    RMMapboxSource *onlineSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"appleweed.control-room"];
    mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:onlineSource];
    //mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.bouncingEnabled = YES;
    mapView.clusteringEnabled = YES;
    mapView.clusterMarkerSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
    mapView.clusterAreaSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
    mapView.zoom = 1;

    RMSphericalTrapezium rect = [mapView latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox];
    mapView.tileCache.backgroundCacheDelegate = self;
    [mapView.tileCache beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource:mapView.tileSource
    southWest:rect.southWest
    northEast:rect.northEast
    minZoom:3.0
    maxZoom:7.0];

}

- (void)tileCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache didBeginBackgroundCacheWithCount:(int)tileCount forTileSource:(id <RMTileSource>)tileSource {

    NSLog(@"start");

}

- (void)tileCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache didBackgroundCacheTile:(RMTile)tile withIndex:(int)tileIndex ofTotalTileCount:(int)totalTileCount {

   // float percentComplete = ((float)tileIndex / (float)totalTileCount) * 100;
    //NSString *update = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", percentComplete];
    //NSLog(@"%@",update);

}

- (void)tileCacheDidFinishBackgroundCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache {

    NSLog(@"DONE!");

}

- (void)tileCacheDidCancelBackgroundCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache {

    NSLog(@"Canceled!");

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it stopping at the same tile count each time? Is there a map view visible at the same time? If you pause your app in the debugger, what is it doing once it seems to have stopped downloading tiles in the background?

Comment: Yes, it stops at the exact same tile count each time. I think it's 242 for the above example. I've tried a few different zooms with the background request. Each has their particular stopping count, but it's consistent each time. If I pause the debugger once my NSLogs have completed and caching appears to have completed, the code is just waiting on the single view I created. Everything just logs to console btw. I also created this test app so to eliminate my own client code just to be safe. My hack checks that the 3 nested loops have ended in the if-then block that tests progTile == totalTile.

Comment: Also, the mapview has been instantiated but not added as a subview of the viewcontroller's view. Btw, am I correctly calling beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource: with the mapview's returned rect from [mapView latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox]? I basically want to just retrieve the tiles in the region currently visible on screen (once the view is added) for the requested zoom levels.

Comment: I should have asked earlier -- can you try the latest `develop` branch and see if the problem still exists there?